# ReactiveCocoa RACObserve on Parse PFObject only works sometimes

Tags: parse-platform, reactive-cocoa, pfobject

I have a main app target called `Foo` with many screens. It's powered by Parse's iOS SDK, so I have model objects which are subclasses of `PFObject`.

I like developing the screens in isolation, so I have separate 'test app' targets that runs a screen in isolation with real models.

There's a screen called `Bar` which heavily relies on KVO observations (`RACObserve`) of  changes on a `PFObject` subclass. e.g. I want to observe a string property on the model in order to generate a diagrammatic view of the text.

I've shown that this  `Bar` works in its test app, and since sources of `Bar` are more or less directly included into `Foo` the same way as it is included into the test app, I expect that any behaviour I see in the test app will also be present in the main application itself.

However, I found that `RACObserve` only works (subscribers are sent their 'next' messages) in the test app, but does not work in the main app (subscribers are not sent their 'next' messages).

I don't understand how `RACObserve` could work in one context and appear to not work in a different context. Help! Using ReactiveCocoa 2.3.1.

Comment: It's hard to guess what could be wrong without seeing your code. Are you sure that the properties of the model are actually being changed in `Bar` (the main app)? Another thing that may break `RACObserve` is method swizzling in the observed object, maybe this is the case?

Comment: Thanks for your reply – I appreciate it's difficult to figure out without code. I've done a bit more investigation and noted my findings in https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1960.

It basically comes down to KVO not working: observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: only gets called if the observer is added earlier in the program. Bewildering.

Comment: The problem's mysteriously disappeared over time, as I thought it would. Weird weird weird!